# The script doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I use node.js so after some operation I use the code :

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'\\showPlayers.html'));
```

to show this html page. The showPlayers.html's code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="giocatori">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Giocatore</th>
        <th>Ruolo</th>
        <th>Costo</th>
        <th>Squadra</th>
        <th>Operazione</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

</table>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("BAU");
var table = document.getElementById("giocatori");

for( var i=0;i<2; i++){
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Mario";
    cell2.innerHTML = "DIF";
    cell3.innerHTML = "10";
    cell4.innerHTML = "Juve";
    cell5.innerHTML = '<form method="post" action="/giocatore"> <input type="submit" name="a" value="Acquista" /> <input type="submit" name="b" value="Cancella" /> </form>';

}
</script>
</html>
```

In the script there is a "`console.log`" and when the node.js program redirect me to this page I see only the thead's table and there is no output from console. If I click on the "showPlayers.html" and I run the page is show correctly. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your `<script>` tag should go in the `<head>...</head>` or `<body>...</body>`, not outside

Comment: Add you `<script>...</script>` tag before `</body>` tag.

Comment: While what the guys above say is true, it's not remotely likely to be the problem. *Edit:* Nope, checked on Chrome, Firefox, IE11, they all happily run the script anyway, as expected; browsers are *really* tolerant of invalid markup.

Comment: I put the script in the body but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is working correctly. The BAU text does go to the console log - but you have to note where this is running. It's in javascript in the browser, so the console log that it goes to is the browser console log, not the node.js console log. If you're in FireFox, for example, you would go to Tools/Web Developer/Browser Console to see the output from your javascript. On my Mac, it shows the following with your html, the first line showing that this comes, correctly, from line 18 in the html file:

[image: BAU text showing up in Browser Console]

When I execute your script, I see the following in my browser. You;ll see your html output on the left and the BAU output to the browser console on the right. 
[image: Image showing html console output]

Running same file from node.js, I get this output in Firefox:
[image: image running node.js]

Are you sure that you're looking for the "BAU" text to appear in the FireFox console window and NOT the node.js window?

Comment: Do you see the raws that I created with my javascript?

Comment: Yes. If you click on the "showPlayes.hmtl"  it works correctly. The problem is if I try to launch hmtl page from node.js server!

Comment: Michael, ran this as a node.js app using ejs as the rendering engine and it works just fine. "BAU" does show up, but it's in the browser console window, not the node.js terminal window. I'm running node v 0.10.40 and ejs v 2.3.3. What are using for your view engine and are you on latest releases? Tested in OSX on FireFox V 40.0.2 and Chrome V 44.0.2403.157 and Safari 8.0.8 and see BAU displayed in each browser's console log window when the html file is served from node.js